# Permission denied while r-x permission on folder

Tags: unix, ssh, permissions, openshift, permission-denied

I'm using openshift and when I ssh to my "server", I can notice two different directories with the EXACT same permissions :

```
[blabla.rhcloud.com 53f5435a5973cac3ab000377]\> ls -lA
total 56
...
drwxr-x---.  3 root  53f5435a5973cac3ab000377 4096 20 août  20:55 .env
...
drwxr-x---.  2 root  53f5435a5973cac3ab000377 4096 20 août  20:55 .ssh
...
```

However, accessing ".env/" (read only) is totally allowed :

```
[blabla.rhcloud.com 53f5435a5973cac3ab000377]\> ls .env/
GEM_HOME           OPENSHIFT_APP_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY  OPENSHIFT_DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH
...
```

But not accessing ".ssh/"... does anyone have a clue ?

```
[blabla.rhcloud.com 53f5435a5973cac3ab000377]\> ls .ssh/
ls: cannot read directory .ssh/: Permission denied.
```

However, I checked who I am and my groups... I should get the "r-x" permission in both cases, right ?

```
[blabla.rhcloud.com 53f5435a5973cac3ab000377]\> whoami
53f5435a5973cac3ab000377
[blabla.rhcloud.com 53f5435a5973cac3ab000377]\> id
uid=5519(53f5435a5973cac3ab000377) gid=5519(53f5435a5973cac3ab000377) groups=5519(53f5435a5973cac3ab000377) context=unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c419
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe better suitable for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

So this probably is better off in unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com but I thought I would answer this anyways. Basically its because they have different SElinux contexts

.env has
`drwxr-x---. root 53ea2aff4382ec8abe00088a system_u:object_r:openshift_var_lib_t:s0:c5,c247 .env`

.ssh has
`drwxr-x---. root 53ea2aff4382ec8abe00088a system_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0:c5,c247 .ssh`